# parseInt crashing

Tags: java, android, crash, parseint

I have a text that looks like this: function 23 34 56 and I need to extract the 23, 34 and 56 as numbers. So I write something like:

```
 String s = "function 2 3 4";
 String[] tokens = (s.trim()).split(" ");
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```

The app crashes here. where could the error be?

I tried finding the length of tokens... comes out to be 4 (for the string "func 23 34 56")... the exception thrown is "numberformatexceptio"... commenting out the parseInt line prevents the crash... i have no clue about what is going wrong... plse help (Android 2.1)

If anyone can post a code to capture the data using regex, that would  be helpful too...thnx..

Comment: tokens[1]?
Are you sure that tokens has anything in it. It may pay to test the length before accessing it.

Comment: Need to know the error message. Appears to be nothing in this fragment of code which would cause an error.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and try logging the value of `tokens[1]`.

Comment: Are you sure app crash here? it looks fine

Answer (score 1):

The code, you posted, runs fine. Nevertheless here is a regex solution:

```
String s = "function 2 3 4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("function\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));
}
```

Comment: thnks henrik for the regex :) ... the parseInt still causes a crash ... you code works smoothly!!

Answer (score -1):

use

```
int[] num=new int[tokens.length];
for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
{
   num[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```